# Android - Why it not cancel repeating alarm?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, broadcast, repeat

I'm set an repeating alarm and it works fine, the problem is just to cancel the **repeating** alarm , I'm able to cancel the triggertime but when I'm set the time 24 hour in future it brings me an error. I know the Intent have to be the same (however I read that the extras are not not necessarily significant). This is the code I use:

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {

    Intent intentBroadCast = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intentBroadCast.putExtra(ID, entry.getC());// /Id setzten auf vektor von
                                                // zugehoerigen Checkbox
    intentBroadCast.putExtra(OPTION, entry.getSelectedOption(entry.getC()));// /Option
                                                                            // die
                                                                            // gewaehlt
                                                                            // wurde
                                                                            // mit
                                                                            // alarm
                                                                            // uebergeben
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, entry.getC(),// /Requestcode um meherere
            intentBroadCast,
            0); // /"einzigartige Alarme zu
                                                // erstellen Alarm
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);// /AlarmManager
                                                        // erzeugen
    alarmManager
            .setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    entry.getTime(entry.getC()), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
                    pendingIntent);// /alle 24h wiederholen solang nicht
                                    // abgeschaltet
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {

    Intent intentBroadCast = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intentBroadCast.putExtra(ID, entry.getC());// /Id setzten auf vektor von
                                                // zugehoerigen Checkbox
    intentBroadCast.putExtra(OPTION, entry.getSelectedOption(entry.getC()));// /Option

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, entry.getC(),
            intentBroadCast, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);// /AlarmManager
                                                        // erzeugen
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: "it brings me an error", what error?

Comment: Im sry it looks like there was another broadcast that triggered when i set the time 24 hour to future. Maybe I seted it while i experimented with it. i've just uninstall complettly and run it again and it worked